# GUI in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface

I am learning to put GUI in Java, now what I want to ask is, should I learn to put the GUI code by myself or should I go for drag and drop method? Which one is preferred and good for me?

Comment: please define: ***to put GUI***???

Comment: Well that depends, but if you're just learning why not use the UI designer and look at the code it generates for you and how it works.

Comment: learn to put the GUI code

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I mean giving my code a nice GUI. JLable , Jtext etc

Comment: Just drag and drop and do the custom in the code that is the best way.  For example  if you drag and drop list view it will not a proper one you have to set over scroll and other things manually

Comment: Im not used to Java GUI. But I use drag and drop in .NET to generate standard code that I alter to my own likings.

Comment: @Badr Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This helps other people with your problem know which solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a beginner**, it is recommended to experiment with the GUI by dragging and dropping and inspect the code that is produced.

**As an expert**, it a much more common practice to code the GUI as you can control many finer details using code instead of manual dragging and dropping.

Comment: Got it, Thank you .